# Install command not working

Tags: server, command-line

Does anyone know why this command isn't working for me,

`sudo dpkg -install webmin_1.620_all.deb`

it says,

`dpkg: error: unknown option - n`

I am following directions on this website: http://refugeeks.com/owncloud-setup-guide/

I am running ubuntu server 12.04 32bit with ssh and lamp installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg` has no `-install`, the correct command is `dpkg -i` or `dpkg --install`. The error means that the command is fine up to the `-i` in `-install`, but the next letter `n` is not a valid option. Use `dpkg --help` to get a list of commands you can use with `dpkg`.

Comment: It was the --install option that worked.  When I did dpkg --help it listed more options than could fit on my screen and I'm not sure how to scroll through the results.

Comment: I'm not sure that should be the case, for me it returns like forty or fifty lines, but anyway, go to `Edit>Profile Preferences>Scrolling` ans set scrollback to unlimited.